# cannot use filter on grep to search for all path including a string

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes

I am having issue to use grep with regular expression 
I am trying to read and filter some logs on server

```
kubectl logs -lname=ambassador --tail=40 | grep ACCESS | grep '" 200 ' | grep ' /api/entitlements '
```

so this returns some logs and it is fine but I need to search for all api including entitlements in their path. I tried this:

```
kubectl logs -lname=ambassador --tail=40 | grep ACCESS | grep '" 200 ' | grep ' *entitlements* '
```

but nothing returns

can anyone help?

Comment: Try: `kubectl logs -lname=ambassador --tail=40 | awk '/ACCESS/ && /" 200 / && /entitlements/'`

Comment: Can you please provide the entire log line, and tell us what part of the line you want to show?

Comment: @franzisk I want to grab all the logs which has this condition  grep ACCESS | grep '" 200 ' entitlements(any string) in it
here is the sample
ACCESS [2020-02-25T16:53:01.534Z] "POST /api/entitlements HTTP/1.1" 200 - 65 593 248 224 "10.128.0.1" "node-fetch/1.0 (+https:/xxx/node-fetch)" "c77e00ac-1556-4bfd-9690-cf59e896db0b" "xxxx.xxxx.com" "172.30.51.162:8443"

Comment: @anubhava that worked can you explain it :)

Comment: Try rearranging you grep command - `kubectl logs -lname=ambassador --tail=40 | grep entitlements| grep '" 200 ' | grep ACCESS`

Answer (score 2):

You may use `awk` to avoid multiple `grep` command and do all filters in one command:

```
kubectl logs -lname=ambassador --tail=40 | awk '/ACCESS/ && /" 200 / && /entitlements/'
```

`/substr/` searches for regex pattern `substr` in each line of `awk`. `&&` ensures that all the given patterns are found in same line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below command to grep multiple keywords -

`kubectl logs -lname=ambassador --tail=40 |grep "entitlements\|ACCESS\| 200"`

Comment: This is ORing so will find matches with just one pattern as well.

Answer (score 1):

Would you try the following:

```
kubectl logs -lname=ambassador --tail=40 | grep -E 'ACCESS.*entitlements.*" 200 '
```

The `grep` searches for the line which contains substrings `ACCESS`, `entitlements`, and `" 200` in this order.